# Time-series x-axis dates from datetimeindex pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the following dataframe, from which I can generate graphs for each sender using .groupby() :

```
                         sender  temp_3
utctime                                
2014-10-24 11:21:08           a    24.7
2014-10-24 11:21:09           b    22.8
2014-10-24 11:21:09           c    23.2
2014-10-24 11:21:09           d    24.3
2014-10-24 11:21:10           e    23.9
2014-10-24 11:21:10           a    24.7
2014-10-24 11:21:11           b    22.9
2014-10-24 11:21:11           c    23.1
2014-10-24 11:21:11           d    24.2
2014-10-24 11:21:12           e    23.9
2014-10-24 11:21:12           a    24.7
2014-10-24 11:21:13           b    22.9
2014-10-24 11:21:13           c    23.1
2014-10-24 11:21:13           d    24.2
2014-10-24 11:21:14           e    23.9
2014-10-24 11:21:14           a    24.7
2014-10-24 11:21:15           b    22.9
2014-10-24 11:21:15           c    23.2
2014-10-24 11:21:15           d    24.1
2014-10-24 11:21:16           e    23.9
```

Here is my code:

```
for key, grp in stack.groupby(['sender']):
    plt.plot(grp.index,
             grp['temp_3'].dropna(),
             label='%s %s' % ('Temperature', key))
```

However, when I apply this to my full dataset, with multiple dates in utctime, the x-axis remains a time - I want it to show the dates in this case.

Here's an example of the full dataset:

```
                    sender  temp_3
utctime                                
2014-10-23 13:15:08           a    23.0
2014-10-24 16:09:13           b    24.1
2014-10-24 18:56:01           a    23.3
2014-10-24 21:42:42           a    23.0
2014-10-25 00:29:22           a    22.7
2014-10-25 03:16:02           c    23.1
2014-10-25 06:02:43           c    22.8
2014-10-25 08:49:23           c    23.7
2014-10-25 11:36:03           c    24.8
2014-10-25 14:22:43           c    25.7
2014-10-25 17:09:24           d    24.9
2014-10-25 19:56:05           b    24.6
2014-10-25 22:42:45           b    24.2
2014-10-26 01:29:26           e    22.7
2014-10-26 04:16:15           d    23.6
2014-10-26 07:02:56           e    22.4
2014-10-26 09:49:36           e    22.7
2014-10-26 12:36:16           e    22.2
2014-10-26 15:22:57           e    23.1
2014-10-26 18:09:46           d    23.8
2014-10-26 20:56:26           b    23.8
2014-10-26 23:43:07           e    22.7
```

I'd post images but need more rep!

I have tried converting .to_julian_time and to_py_datetime after following some other stack posts. I've also tried grp.index.date, but this still gives a time in the x-axis, and is worse because it loses the detail. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `plt.plot_date(...)`?

Comment: Just tried it, but still the same problem

Comment: I'll add some data with different dates above if you'd like to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the format on the xaxis should do the trick:

```
plotaxis = plt.figure().gca()
plotaxis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y\n%H:%M'))
for key, grp in stack.groupby(['sender']):
plt.plot(grp.index,
         grp['temp_3'].dropna(),
         label='%s %s' % ('Temperature', key))
```

Comment: This works well. I tried the same trick on a subplot where I'd split each sender into a separate dataframe, and the DateFormatter threw up a value error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html, perhaps you're not applying it to the subplot's axis ('ax' in the demo code: fig, ax = plt.subplots()).